# Suppress Matplotlib Legend Warning in IPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, warnings

I am creating a plot with a large amount of data and adding a legend to it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot(np.arange(100000), np.random.random((100000, 10)), label='data')
plt.legend()
```

This generates a warning (as expected), when the legend actually gets drawn in another thread:

```
<matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x1b5824d04c8>C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\eventloops.py:106: UserWarning: Creating legend with loc="best" can be slow with large amounts of data.
  app.exec_()
```

I would like to suppress this specific warning, so I do

```
from warnings import filterwarnings
filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module="matplotlib")
```

Running the same plotting code again produces the same warning.

How do I suppress it? Ideally, I would like to use [`warnings.catch_warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings) around the call to `legend`. Something like

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    plt.legend()
```

The original commands were run in interactive mode in spyder (ipython) using a `Qt5agg` backend. I also ran the same commands followed by `plt.show()` in a plain python console:

```
__main__:1: UserWarning: Creating legend with loc="best" can be slow with large amounts of data.
```

Running `filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module="__main__")`
helps, but only in non-interactive mode. In interactive mode, the
following warning is issued:

```
C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\console.py:514: UserWarning: Creating legend with loc="best" can be slow with large amounts of data.
  call_function(inputHookFunc, ())
```

The issue seems to be ipython specific. I am using

Python 3.8.3, IPython 7.16.1, matplotlib 3.2.2 (, and numpy 1.18.5)

Comment: @Mr.T I tested outside ipython and did not get the warning, so pretty sure that you're right about the source of the problem.

Comment: just tested on Jupyter and no warnings (but I have some general settings such as `%matplotlib inline` and `%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'`). Do you have a complete script along with how you run it? Also, it looks like you are running on Windows???

Comment: @PierreD that's the full script. I don't do inline plotting is the only difference.

Comment: where is the output image expected?  Don't you have at least a `%pylab` or equivalent?

Comment: BTW, if I run your script (preceded with `%pylab`) it takes a long time but works just fine. Without `%pylab`, then it also takes a long time, but completes without error (and no plot --or if there is one that is generated, I don't know where it goes; there are no new files in `cwd`). This is with: `python 3.8.5; ipython 7.19.0; matplotlib 3.3.2` and on MacOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer shows how to suppress the legend warning as per the OP heading. It doesn't explain how to temporarily catch the warning once it has been issued. If you're interested in the latter than the following is more a workaround than an answer.

According to the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/4e4410df1f73bff527c93ccb828dbd9b2eae139f/lib/matplotlib/legend.py#L1055) the warning is shown if the default loaction is used (from `rcParams['legend.loc']` which is `'best'` by default) and it takes more than 1 sec to find the best location. If you explicitly set the location to `'best'` no warning will be issued.

Tested on Windows, both IPython and plain command line (I had to increase the number on my machine):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
plt.plot(np.arange(1_000_000), np.random.random((1_000_000, 10)), label='data')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

---

As an alternative you could permanently suppress the warning by its *message* (instead of *module*):

```
filterwarnings("ignore", 'Creating legend with loc="best" can be slow with large amounts of data.')
```

The drawback is that it's permanent. I couldn't find a way to suppress the warning temporarily by using a context manage as the context of course closes long before the legend position calculation takes place.
To revert this change to the warnings filters list you can do one of the following **after** the legend is finally drawn: `warnings.filters = [w for w in warnings.filters if not w[1] or not re.match(w[1], 'Creating legend with loc="best" can be slow with large amounts of data.')]` or `filterwarnings("default", 'Creating legend with loc="best" can be slow with large amounts of data.')`.